# OPENXML cuts input based on the given WITH datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following TSQL script:

```
declare @ValuesXML nvarchar(max), @handle int

set @ValuesXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                  <Values>
                      <Value code="TUIRWERTYU"/>
                  </Values>
                  '

exec dbo.sp_xml_preparedocument @handle output, @ValuesXML

create table #test(val nvarchar(1))

insert into #test (val)
select code
  from openxml( @handle, '/Values/Value', 1) 
  with (code nvarchar(1))

select * from #test

drop table #test
```

When I am running it I am expecting having an error similar to

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Since `code="TUIRWERTYU"` has 10 characters but I am 'declaring' only one character for reading that field in the following statement `with (code nvarchar(1))`

However the script run without any error. The output of the select statement is

> T

Which means that my values were truncated to fit the column declaration.

Why this is happening? I couldn't find any documentation that explains it.

Comment: Truncation errors are generated *only* when you attempt to store a string in a table column (including columns of table variables) that isn't large enough to hold it. In all other scenarios (parameters, variables), conversion will implicitly truncate. It's one of T-SQL's many delights (along with the truncation error not indicating what column of what table was involved).

Comment: Hm I see! So whatever is in `WITH` clause is considered as variable. However the documentation says, `In SchemaDeclaration, in the WITH clause, ColPattern is also specified with the ColName and ColType parameters.`, so I thought that in the 'WITH' you are declaring a table structure.

Comment: You'd think so, wouldn't you? Especially since it also allows you to supply the schema from an existing table. But as you've experimentally discovered, apparently it uses the same implicit conversion rules as usual. If you declared `with (code nvarchar(2))`, you *will* get a truncation error, when the `insert` attempts to store the result in `#test` -- so one possible workaround is to use `nvarchar(max)` for all strings, then leave any truncation error (if you want them for some reason) up to the final insert.